# how would I query 4/1/ of the 72nd birth date year > an input date

Tags: oracle10g

I have tried the following:

```
add_months(to_Date('04/01/ind.birth_dte','MM/DD/YYYY'), 864) >= to_date('&StartDt','MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Is there a better way to pull April first of the participant's 72nd birth date?

Comment: April 1st of the year in which their 72 birthday falls; or the April 1st when their age is 72? You seem to want the former - so anyone born on any date in 1900 will give an answer of 1972-04-01, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an interval calculation instead, but not sure how you're defining 'better'. Assuming you do want April 1st of the year in which their 72 birthday falls:

```
trunc(ind.birth_dte, 'YYYY') + interval '72-3' year to month
```

The [`trunc()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) goes to the first day of their birth year, and the interval adds 72 years and 3 months to that, which will be April 1st.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/22902) with some sample dates, including a leap day to show that isn't a problem.

Or to compare that adjusted date with a fixed date as a filter:

```
where trunc(ind.birth_dte, 'YYYY') + interval '72-3' year to month
  > to_date('&StartDt','MM/DD/YYYY');
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/22904).

You can use the `trunc()` method with your version as well to save building up a string and calling `to_date`, adding an additional three months to the `add_months` call (though I'd suggest you at least need a comment indicating where '867' comes from):

```
where add_months(trunc(ind.birth_dte, 'YYYY'), 867)
  > to_date('&StartDt','MM/DD/YYYY');
```